# How do I translate a page in java with lot of text,without using resource bundle?

Tags: java, language-translation

I have a web page with lots of text.Is there any means through which I can translate it,without using resource bundle(which involves using properties files,requiring key value pairs for all words.)?

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: The i18n issue is best solved with a `.properties` file as you said. Other options would be to persist different texts in different languages in your DB and display the needed one.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to create separate views for each language. So a "mypage_en_US.html" for the US-english version and a "mypage_en_GB.html" for the british-english version. This gives you total control over the text and layout but has the drawback of possible code duplication if there is any logic in your view.

[Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) uses pretty clean views which should hardly contain any logic so [this works pretty well](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/localization-and-skinning-of-applications.html) there.

Answer (score 0):

Just be innovative here. If you are getting shitty copy pase work. Write a program to convert the properties file and then use that properties file using google translate api, but yeah end of the day you will have to go with properties file.

I belive there would be other way too using google translate api again, would love to hear that myself too

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your web framework.

For example, Wicket can apply I18N on webpages in two ways :
- using I18N files and resourcesbundles, with placeholders where required in the page
- by having totally separate pages, one for each language. The page template itself is postfixed with the locale, much like property files : HomePage_en.html, HomePage_fr.html, etc.

Other web frameworks may have similar features. If you're using raw JSP/Servlets, I'm afraid you're pretty much on your own.
But it's totally possible to implement your own templating system. For example, you could use a set of Freemarker templates, and load the one that matches the desired locale.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple pages suggestion...could you elaborate or provide a link on wicket's usage

Comment: Sure. Here is the link to wicket's documentation page on I18N : https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/i18n.html